# How to see the saved data file in Android phone

Tags: java, android, save, load

My code is about saving data (hello world in a text file names ( hello.txt ) )
my code has no problems and it run well ... but I can't find my hello.txt in my phone at all ! .. I used File Manager to find it but I still can't find it 
P.S : my phone is not rooted

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    String FILENAME = "hello.txt";
    String string = "hello world!";

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openFileOutput()` will place the file in a private internal directory where no other app has access. Try to use external memory instead. Use `getExternalFilesDir()`.

It then will be in something like

```
  /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<packagename>/files
  /storage/sdcar0/Android/data/<packagename>/files
```

and many more such paths possible.

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in:

> `/data/data/packagename/files/`

Comment: you're not going to find it in a file browser on the device unless your phone is rooted but you should be able to use adb to look at it